# Can I upload file with this code in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

```
$judul = $_POST['judul'];
$idKategori = $_POST['kategori'];
$idPropinsi = $_POST['propinsi'];
$img = $_FILES['img']['name'];
$img_tmp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
$idUser = $_POST['user'];
$isi = $_POST['isi'];
$date = $_POST['date'];

if(empty($img)) {
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `artikel`(`idArtikel`, `idKategori`, `idPropinsi`, `judul`, `idUser`, `isi`, `date`) VALUES ('','$idKategori','$idPropinsi','$judul','$idUser','$isi','$date')");
}else{
    if(move_uploaded_file($img_tmp,"../../../img/".$img)) {
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `artikel`(`idArtikel`, `idKategori`, `idPropinsi`, `judul`, `img`, `idUser`, `isi`, `date`) VALUES ('','$idKategori','$idPropinsi','$judul','$img','$idUser','$isi','$date')");
    }else{
        echo "Failed to upload image";
    }
}

if($query) {
    header("location:../../index.php?page=artikel");
}else{
    echo "failed to update this post";
}
```

But the result is

> move_uploaded_file(http://localhost/mvc/kuliner/assets/img/Green Nature Wallpapers 04.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Comment: this is php file upload function not codeigniter file upload function

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: @saty Is the input name should named 'userfile' like in the codeigniter example or I can name it whatever i want?

Comment: you can give your name also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No!

Basically rewriting this code to work with Codeigniter is a lot more work than writing it from scratch using examples found in the CI documentation. Link provided in comment above (http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/file_uploading.html).

There are several reasons as both file upload, redirection, database handling, user output etcetera are done differently in CI using CI's methods and the MVC structure of programming.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do my uploads in CI (Using Dropzone).

Create `Dropzone` Controller

```
class Dropzone extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->helper(array('url','html','form')); 
}


public function upload() {
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $temp = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $path_parts = pathinfo($temp);
    $t = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', microtime());
    $fileName = $path_parts['filename']. $t . '.' . $path_parts['extension'];
    $targetPath = UPLOADPATH;
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $fileName ;
    echo $fileName;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
    // if you want to save in db,where here
    // with out model just for example
    // $this->load->database(); // load database
    // $this->db->insert('file_table',array('file_name' => $fileName));
    }
}
}
   // Usage : <form action="<?php echo site_url('/dropzone/upload');" class="dropzone"  >

 /* End of file dropzone.js */
 /* Location: ./application/controllers/dropzone.php */
```

Secondly Add the following HTML, (mainly to a form so as to submit file name

```
 <div id="upload" class="form-group">
            <label>Drop file Here</label>
            <input type="hidden" id="file" name="file"/>
            <div
                class="dropzone"
                id="uploadFile"><!--uploadFile is the dropzone name-->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then a little Js to do the magic

```
Dropzone.options.uploadFile = {
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    url:"<?php echo site_url('/dropzone/upload');?>",
    maxFiles:1,
    acceptedFiles:'image/*,application/pdf,.docx,.doc,.xls,.xlsx,.csv',
    dictMaxFilesExceeded:"You can only upload one file per Response",
    init: function() {
        this.on("sending", function(file) { 
           // $('button#submit').attr('disabled','');// Requires Jquery
        });
        this.on("complete", function(file) { 
            //$('button#submit').removeAttr('disabled'); // Requires JQuery
        });
        this.on("success", function(file,xhr) { 
            //$('input[type="hidden"]#file').val(xhr); // Requires Jquery
        });
     }
};
```

Remember to include dropzone.js and jquery.js if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload files using the PHP function. But at first, you should make the directory or folder by yourself.

Here is my code, I did not add the validation part. I have created the `uploads` folder in the root directory.

```
$file = $_FILES['verfication_image'];
$file_name_with_extenstion = $file['name'];
$file_name = pathinfo($file_name_with_extenstion, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = pathinfo($file_name_with_extenstion, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file_tmp_location =$_FILES['verfication_image']['tmp_name'];
$upload_name = $file_name.time().".$extension";
if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_location,"uploads/".$upload_name)){
    echo "The file has been uploaded.";
}else{
    echo "There was an error.";
}
```

I would suggest using the Codeigniter version of uploading the file as it is simple to add validation. I have added my Codeigniter code with validation,

```
$file = $_FILES['verfication_image'];
$file_name_with_extenstion = $file['name'];
$file_name = pathinfo($file_name_with_extenstion, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = pathinfo($file_name_with_extenstion, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$upload_name = $file_name.time().".$extension";

$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
$config['file_name'] = $upload_name;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = 1024;
$config['max_width'] = 1024;
$config['max_height'] = 768;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);//Load the libary with the configuration

if(!$this->upload->do_upload('verfication_image')){
    echo($this->upload->display_errors());//validation error will be printed
}else{
    echo "The file has been uploaded.";
}
```

For more details, please follow the official guideline [File Uploading class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)